# Plotly: Setting the marker size based on the column in the exported data?

Tags: python, dataframe, error-handling, plotly, size

The code is running well; however, in my dataset, there is a column SD in my custom dataset. I would like the size of these markers should be based on SD and I did it in the seaborn library, it is running well. However, I get errors here.

%Error is
**Did you mean "line"?
Bad property path:
size
^^^^**

Code is

```
df=pd.read_csv("Lifecycle.csv")

df1=df[df["Specie"]=="pot_marigold"]
df1
df2=df[df["Specie"]=="Sunflowers"]
df2
trace=go.Scatter(x=df1["Days"], y=df1["Lifecycle"],text=df1["Specie"],marker={"color":"green"}, size=df1[SD],
mode="lines+markers")
trace1=go.Scatter(x=df2["Days"], y=df2["Lifecycle"],text=df2["Specie"],marker={"color":"red"},
mode="lines+markers")
data=[trace,trace1] 
layout=go.Layout(
    title="Lifecycle",
    xaxis={"title":"Days"},
    yaxis={"title":"Lifecycle"})

fig=go.Figure(data=data,layout=layout)
pyo.plot(fig)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- you have not provided sample data, so I have simulated based on what I can imply from your code
- simply you can set **marker_size** within framework you have used
- this type of plot is far simpler with **Plotly Express** have also shown code for this

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go

# df=pd.read_csv("Lifecycle.csv")
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Specie": np.repeat(["pot_marigold", "Sunflowers"], 10),
        "Days": np.tile(np.arange(1, 11, 1), 2),
        "Lifecycle": np.concatenate(
            [np.sort(np.random.uniform(1, 5, 10)).astype(int) for _ in range(2)]
        ),
        "SD": np.random.randint(1, 8, 20),
    }
)

df1 = df[df["Specie"] == "pot_marigold"]
df2 = df[df["Specie"] == "Sunflowers"]
trace = go.Scatter(
    x=df1["Days"],
    y=df1["Lifecycle"],
    text=df1["Specie"],
    marker={"color": "green"},
    marker_size=df1["SD"],
    mode="lines+markers",
)
trace1 = go.Scatter(
    x=df2["Days"],
    y=df2["Lifecycle"],
    text=df2["Specie"],
    marker={"color": "red"},
    mode="lines+markers",
)
data = [trace, trace1]
layout = go.Layout(
    title="Lifecycle", xaxis={"title": "Days"}, yaxis={"title": "Lifecycle"}
)

fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)

fig
```

[image]

#### Plotly Express

```
import plotly.express as px

px.scatter(
    df,
    x="Days",
    y="Lifecycle",
    color="Specie",
    size="SD",
    color_discrete_map={"pot_marigold": "green", "Sunflowers": "red"},
).update_traces(mode="lines+markers")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `plotly.express` instead:

```
import plotly.express as px

trace=px.scatter(df, x="Days", y="Lifecycle", text="Specie", marker="SD")
```